# Route traffic + DNS through SSH (ie.: socks proxy)

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, windows-10, socks

I have the following setup:

- 2 computers (`Cmp.A` and `Cmp.B`)
- Computers run Windows 10 and I have admin rights on both machines
- Cmp.A is simultaneously connected to 2 VPN networks (different domains) using different solutions
- Cmp.A has got OpenSSH server installed and enabled
- Cmp.B should access the internet and all private domains (coming through the VPNs) via Cmp.A
- Cmp.B should resolve host names through Cmp.A
  in other words: DNS traffic should be resolved through Cmp.A as well

Currently, I achieve this by connecting to Cmp.B to Cmp.A via SSH which gives me a SOCKS proxy in the SSH tunnel. Cmp.B has got **ProxyCap** installed which routes all traffic (including DNS) to Cmp.A.

This setup works pretty well for me, but there's one ugly setback: ProxyCap does change the Winsock configuration of my Windows 10 (on Cmp.B) which results in incompatibility problems with my other applications. When I execute `netsh winsock show catalog` it does return dozens of new entries related to ProxyCap and I don't want this (if possible)

I would like to avoid using ProxyCap and save myself from an application messing around with such OS level socket settings, but I need all traffic (not just browser traffic) to go through Cmp.B.

**Wrapping it up, my questions are:**

- How do I route all Win10 network traffic (including DNS) thorough another Windows 10 computer (over an SSH SOCKS5 proxy) without using ProxyCap?
- How do I make Windows to resolve DNS through my already existing SOCKS5 tunnel?